# Boost scoped_ptr / scoped_array with custom deleter

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I don't see how to get **scoped_ptr** or **scoped_array** to use a custom deleter. Maybe there is another implementation which allows controlled deletion similar to **shared_ptr**?

Btw, why does **shared_ptr** allow custom deleter but **scoped_ptr** doesn't? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't see how to get `scoped_ptr` or `scoped_array` to use custom deleter

You can't.

> Maybe there is another implementation which allows controlled deletion similar to `shared_ptr`?

If your compiler supports rvalue references and your Standard Library implementation implements `std::unique_ptr`, you can use that.

Otherwise, the `boost::scoped_ptr` implementation is very straightforward.  [The latest version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp) is less than 100 lines of simple code.  It would be quite simple to create your own derivative that has a custom deleter (either a static via a template parameter or dynamic via a function or functor provided at runtime).

Comment: scoped_ptr is simple, but enabling controlled deletion won't be that straightforward. Not as complex as shared_ptr, but still I would prefer not code it if a library solution is available.

Answer (score 3):

`scoped_ptr` doesn't allow custom deleter. The main reason as I can suppose is that its' size will not be equal to `sizeof(T*)` if it would keep a `boost::function<>` as `shared_ptr` does.

I think the most portable options are to use `shared_ptr` or to write your own `scoped_ptr` that will support deleters.

Comment: unique_ptr allows a custom deleter, and if that custom deleter is an "empty" class (as is the default deleter), then sizeof(unique_ptr) == sizeof(T*).

Answer (score 3):

You can overload boost::checked_delete function, e.g.

```
namespace boost {

template<>
void checked_delete (Foo* x)
{
    ....
}

} // namespace boost
```

After overloading, scoped_ptr will call checked_delete rather than delete.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation of scoped pointer and scoped array is found in Qt

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html

It allows for custom deleter.

Comment: Different custom deleters create different pointer types, but implementation should be simpler than using generic delegates.

Comment: I don't know another implementation that is simpler. Would you kindly give one?

Comment: I meant that QT's implementation should be simpler than using generic delegates such as boost::function. Performance should be be better too. But you end up with different pointer types for each different deleter types (deleter is template parameter)